# Known issues in Java 7

Tags: java

Tachnology is maturing day by day but there remains issues. I want to know the known issues in JAVA 7. I encountered one: Outpost blocks Java 7. With the firewall turned off Java runs without problems.

Comment: This is not a forum; __this is a questions and answer site, and I'm afraid your post isn't really a question, because [real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).__ [Please read the FAQ for more information.](http://stackoverflow.com//faq)

Comment: FAQ says: if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK. From this question people will know the problems in JAVA7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the release documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk7-relnotes-418459.html#knownissues